# strtod change last digit

Tags: strtod

someone can explain to me what is happening?

```
double dbl = stdtod("9999999999999999", NULL);
```

I got the value: `9999999999999998`
and not: `9999999999999999`

I don't understand why this happen, in the MSDN, is specified that the max double number is `1.7976931348623158E+308`, so it can't be a overflow.

Thanks

Comment: But it doesn't say that all the numbers in between the minimum and the max are representable. Gory details in ["What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic"](http://www.engrng.pitt.edu/hunsaker/3097/floatingpoint.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Its not an overflow its an issue with how floating point works.  You have a limited nubmer of significant digits that is exceeded long before you get an overflow. This has been linked hear many times but check out [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)